# alternate tag to perform keyboard actions with PAF instead of <robot tag>?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I want to perform some keyboard actions using pace automation framework. There is a  but i need to use different tag. Is there any tag regarding with keyboard actions. Please guide me with a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

YES, we can use  to perform keyboard actions.

Syntax: <specialKeys id/name/css/xpath/className="" specialChar="">